# iAds displaying portrait in landscape orientation from start

Tags: iphone, orientation, landscape, iad, adwhirl

I got this iPhone app where I use AdWhirl to change between a number of ad networks. Now when iAds gets its turn in and the phone is in landscape orientation before the ad shows it will display the normal portrait iAd. If I then turn the phone to portrait and back to landscape it shows the correct longer and thinner landscape version of the iAd.

So why is it displaying the small version if the phone is in landscape mode before showing the ad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was as simple as just turning it whenever I receive a new ad:

```
- (void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView { 

    [adWhirlView rotateToOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
    [self adjustAdSize];

}
```